# Storing variable names in a struct

Tags: matlab

I am dealing with a rather large optimization problem (using MOSEK). To remind myself of the decision variables in this problem, I decided to try to store the variable names in a cell array in a struct, [as desribed by MOSEK](http://docs.mosek.com/7.0/toolbox/Command_reference.html#ch-cmdref-sec-names). However, I am unsure of how to do this. The relevant fragment of my code is listed below:

```
JiSet = 1:6; TiSet = [7 8]; nL = length(TiSet); 
P = struct;
P.names.var{1} = 'gamma_i(k+1)';    % my first constraint
P.names.var{2:1+nL,1} = cellstr(strcat('nu_',int2str(TiSet(:)),'(k+1)')); % a series of constraints of varying length
```

When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.
```

However, if I enter `strcat('nu_',int2str(TiSet(:)),'(k+1)')` in my command window, it shows an `ans` variable that is a 2x1 cell (as desired). How do I assign the values in this cell to the `2:1+nL,1` entries in the `P.names.var` cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the same line with round brackets `( )`, which are used to select sets of cells.

```
P.names.var(2:1+nL,1) = cellstr(strcat('nu_',int2str(TiSet(:)),'(k+1)'));
```

---

`MyCell{1:2}` refers to the literal contents of the cells.

```
MyCell = {10,24,-60};
MyCell{1:2}

ans =

    10


ans =

    24
```

`MyCell(1:2)` refers to a collection of cells.

```
MyCell(1:2)

ans = 

    [10]    [24]
```

Since `cellstr(strcat('nu_',int2str(TiSet(:)),'(k+1)'));` is a collection of cells, you need to assign it to a collection of cells, `P.names.var(2:1+nL,1);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you structure your assignment in the last line. The right-hand side creates a single value, a 2x1 cell array. However, the left-hand refers to two separate fields. This behavior is likely a result of the nature of cell-arrays, which may except a different data-type in each cell. Cell arrays are set up to assign whatever is on the right-hand side to a single cell on the left-hand side. You can fix this with a simple modification:

```
P.names.var(2:1+nL,1) = cellstr(strcat('nu_',int2str(TiSet(:)),'(k+1)'));
```

This utilizes "array indexing" as opposed to "cell indexing".